# Build.xml in target folder is not updated with the jar dependencies newly added -- using ant to build

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

My Project build.xml is

```
<project name="timesheet" default="build_war" basedir=".">

<property file="${basedir}/properties/local.properties"/>
<property name="build.root.dir" value="${BUILD_ROOT}"/>
<property name="jboss.home" value="${JBOSS_HOME}"/>
<property name="env.java.home" value="${JAVA_HOME}"/>
<property name="deploy.dir" value="${DEPLOY_DIR}"/>
<property name="build.output.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/${APPSERVER}"/>
<property name="build.target.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/target"/>
<property name="build.deploy.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/deploy"/>
<property name="build.source.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/src"/>
<property name="build.lib.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/lib"/>
<property name="build.classes.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="build.app.name" value="${APPNAME}" />



<path id="3rdparty.path">
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/activation.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/antlr-2.7.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/antlr.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/autonumber-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bcel.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bindingservice-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bsf.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bsh-deployer.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bsh.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/cglib.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-chain-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-collections.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-digester-1.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-httpclient.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-io-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-logging.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/crypt.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/dom4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/ejb3-persistence.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/el-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hibernate-entitymanager.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hibernate3.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hsqldb-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hsqldb.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/javassist.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jaxen.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-cache-jdk50.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-ejb3x.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-hibernate.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-j2ee.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jaxrpc.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jaxws.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jca.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jsr77.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jsr88.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-management.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-monitoring.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-remoting-int.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-remoting.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-saaj.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-serialization.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-srp.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-transaction.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-vfs.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossjta-integration.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossjta.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossmq.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbosssx.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossts-common.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossws-common.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossws-framework.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossws-jboss42.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossws-spi.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jmx-adaptor-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jnpserver.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/joesnmp.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jpl-pattern.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jpl-util.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jsch-0.1.55.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jsp-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/log4j-1.2.9.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/log4j-snmp-appender.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/log4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/mail-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/mail.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/ldap-authentication-api-1.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/properties-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/quartz.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/scheduler-plugin-example.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/scheduler-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-core-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-el-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-extras-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-faces-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-mailreader-dao-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-scripting-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-taglib-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/xmlentitymgr.jar"/>
    
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.uguess.birt.report.engine.emitter.rtf_2.5.2.201107181644.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.200.v20130326-1319.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20130513-1956.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb_2.10.1.v20130422-1135.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.301.v20130717-1549.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.100.v20130422-1538.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20130327-1442.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.emf_2.6.0.v20130902-0605.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.9.1.v20130827-0309.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.9.1.v20130827-0309.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.9.0.v20130827-0309.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.emf.common_2.9.1.v20130827-0309.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle_1.0.0.v201107221506.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.dbdefinition_1.0.103.v201206010214.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity_1.2.9.v201307261105.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.4.1.v201308160907.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design_3.3.6.v201212070447.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer_3.2.6.v201305170644.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.dbdefinition.genericJDBC_1.0.1.v201107221459.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.db.generic_1.0.1.v201107221459.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.core.resources_3.8.101.v20130717-0806.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.300.v20130429-1813.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.core.filesystem_1.4.0.v20130514-1240.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.4.500.v20130515-1343.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.200.v20130326-1255.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.birt.runtime-4.3.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.3.1.v20130918-1142.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.nativexls_1.0.0.201110011404.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.csv_1.0.0.201110121016.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.xml.resolver_1.2.0.v201005080400.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.xml_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.util_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.util.gui_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.transcoder_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.svggen_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.pdf_1.6.0.v201105071520.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.parser_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.ext.awt_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.dom_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.dom.svg_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.css_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/org.apache.batik.bridge_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/log4j-1.2.9.jar"/>

    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/poi-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/poi-examples-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/poi-excelant-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jersey-common.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jersey-container-servlet-core.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jersey-container-servlet.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jersey-server.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hk2-api-2.3.0-b10.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hk2-locator-2.3.0-b10.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hk2-utils-2.3.0-b10.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jersey-guava-2.13.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jersey-client.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/java-json.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/AsOneModel.jar"/>
</path>

<path id="jboss.path">
    <fileset dir="${jboss.home}/server/timesheet/lib">
        <include name="javax.servlet*.jar"/>
        <include name="jboss-j2ee.jar"/>
        <include name="activation.jar"/>
        <include name="mail.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <path refid="3rdparty.path"/>
</path>

<target name="settings">
    <echo message="build.output.dir : ${build.output.dir}"/>
    <echo message="jboss.home : ${jboss.home}" />   
</target >

<target name="compile_timesheet" >
    <delete dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${build.source.dir}" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" deprecation="off" failonerror="true" debug="true" memorymaximumsize="256m" fork="true">
        <classpath refid="3rdparty.path"/>
        <include name="com/**/*.java"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="build_war"  depends="compile_timesheet">
    <delete dir="${build.target.dir}/${build.app.name}.war"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.target.dir}/${build.app.name}.war"/>
    <copy overwrite="yes" todir="${build.target.dir}/${build.app.name}.war/">
        <fileset dir="${build.root.dir}/WebRoot" />
    </copy>
    <copy overwrite="yes" todir="${build.target.dir}/${build.app.name}.war/WEB-INF/classes/" >
        <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy overwrite="yes" todir="${build.target.dir}/${build.app.name}.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/cnsi/timesheet/" >
       <fileset dir="${build.root.dir}/resources" includes="**/*.properties"/>
    </copy>
    <delete dir="${deploy.dir}/deploy/${build.app.name}.war"/>

    <mkdir dir="${deploy.dir}/deploy/${build.app.name}.war"/>

    <copy overwrite="yes" todir="${deploy.dir}/deploy/${build.app.name}.war" >
        <fileset dir="${build.target.dir}/${build.app.name}.war" />
    </copy>


    </target>
```

and my target build.xml is

```
<project name="timesheet" default="build_war" basedir=".">

<property file="${basedir}/properties/local.properties"/>
<property name="build.root.dir" value="${BUILD_ROOT}"/>
<property name="jboss.home" value="${JBOSS_HOME}"/>
<property name="env.java.home" value="${JAVA_HOME}"/>
<property name="deploy.dir" value="${DEPLOY_DIR}"/>
<property name="build.output.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/${APPSERVER}"/>
<property name="build.deploy.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/deploy"/>
<property name="build.source.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/src"/>
<property name="build.lib.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/lib"/>
<property name="build.classes.dir" value="${build.root.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="build.app.name" value="${APPNAME}" />

<path id="3rdparty.path">
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/activation.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/antlr-2.7.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/antlr.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/autonumber-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bcel.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bindingservice-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bsf.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bsh-deployer.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/bsh.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/cglib.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-chain-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-collections.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-digester-1.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-httpclient.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-io-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-logging.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/crypt.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/dom4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/ejb3-persistence.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/el-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hibernate-entitymanager.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hibernate3.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hsqldb-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/hsqldb.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/javassist.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jaxen.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-cache-jdk50.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-ejb3x.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-hibernate.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-j2ee.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jaxrpc.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jaxws.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jca.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jsr77.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-jsr88.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-management.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-monitoring.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-remoting-int.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-remoting.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-saaj.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-serialization.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-srp.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-transaction.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss-vfs.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jboss.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossjta-integration.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossjta.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossmq.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbosssx.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossts-common.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossws-common.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossws-framework.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossws-jboss42.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jbossws-spi.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jmx-adaptor-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jnpserver.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/joesnmp.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jpl-pattern.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jpl-util.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jsp-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/log4j-1.2.9.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/log4j-snmp-appender.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/log4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/mail-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/mail.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/mysql-connector-java-3.1.12-bin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/properties-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/quartz.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/scheduler-plugin-example.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/scheduler-plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-core-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-el-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-extras-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-faces-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-mailreader-dao-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-scripting-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-taglib-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/xmlentitymgr.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/java-json.jar"/>
</path>

<path id="jboss.path">
    <fileset dir="${jboss.home}/server/timesheet/lib">
        <include name="javax.servlet*.jar"/>
        <include name="jboss-j2ee.jar"/>
        <include name="activation.jar"/>
        <include name="mail.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <path refid="3rdparty.path"/>
</path>

<target name="settings">
    <echo message="build.output.dir : ${build.output.dir}"/>
    <echo message="jboss.home : ${jboss.home}" />   
</target >

<target name="compile_timesheet" >
    <delete dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${build.source.dir}" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" deprecation="off" failonerror="true" debug="true" memorymaximumsize="256m" fork="true">
        <classpath refid="3rdparty.path"/>
        <include name="com/**/*.java"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="build_war"  depends="compile_timesheet">
    <delete dir="${build.source.dir}/${build.app.name}.war"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.source.dir}/${build.app.name}.war"/>
    <copy overwrite="yes" todir="${build.source.dir}/${build.app.name}.war/">
        <fileset dir="${build.root.dir}/WebRoot" />
    </copy>
    <copy overwrite="yes" todir="${build.source.dir}/${build.app.name}.war/WEB-INF/classes/" >
        <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <delete dir="${deploy.dir}/deploy/${build.app.name}.war"/>

    <mkdir dir="${deploy.dir}/deploy/${build.app.name}.war"/>

    <copy overwrite="yes" todir="${deploy.dir}/deploy/${build.app.name}.war" >
        <fileset dir="${build.source.dir}/${build.app.name}.war" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

I am creating a war file after deployment, but unable to find the jar dependency in the build.xml in target folder.

I have added
`<pathelement path="${build.lib.dir}/jsch-0.1.55.jar"/>` in build.xml and added the jar in lib folder.

After building the project I have seen that the jar is not found and the build.xml in target folder doesn't contain the jar path as I added in project's build.xml

Can someone tell me how can I deploy it with new jar dependency I added.

Comment: Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should add the detailed configurations from build.xml, directory listing and full error messages. Also version of ANT and tooling used.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.